# Is it statistically possible that i use the same statistic by changing the hypothesis interpretation?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, t-test

I want to test the correlation coefficient (i.e. |ρ|=1) that the relationship among variables is deterministic. If sample correlation coefficient ( r=0.93) can i test this value ( 1-r=1-0.93=0.07) using t-statistic ((r√(n-2))⁄√(1-r^2 )) with the statement that the relationship among variables is stochastic (i.e. ρ=0) or no relationship with 5% level of significance.

Answer (score 0):

Failure to reject a null hypothesis does not establish equivalence. You probably want to do an equivalent test of correlation coefficients. The paper below focuses on this exact issue.

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/bmsp.12045/abstract;jsessionid=279A5F4637E7DF195162EC836B860FB7.f04t03

Comment: Wouldn't that require comparing correlations from two populations?

Comment: yes, not require comparing of two correlations @dankernler